# Setting a pandas sub dataframe indexed with a MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a `pandas.DataFrame` with a Multi such as:

```
In [298]: pd.DataFrame(index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([['a', 1], ['a', 2], ['b', 1], ['b', 3]]), data={'x': 1})
Out[298]: 
     x
a 1  1
  2  1
b 1  1
  3  1
```

When i want to reassign a sub dataframe ie (`df.loc['a']`), i get a weird output:

```
In [300]: df.loc['a'] = df.loc['a']

In [301]: df
Out[301]: 
      x
a 1 NaN
  2 NaN
b 1   1
  3   1
```

The example is simple, i obviously intent to have a reassignment more complicated.

Is it normal? How can i reassign a sub dataframe indexed with a MultiIndex?

Comment: you can do it this way: `df.loc[df.index.get_level_values(0) == 'a'] = df`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[[..]]` (update the DataFrame rather than the Series):

```
In [11]: df
Out[11]:
     x
a 1  1
  2  1
b 1  1
  3  1

In [12]: df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([['a', 1], ['a', 2], ['b', 1], ['b', 3]]), data={'x': 2})

In [13]: df.loc[["a"]] = df2.loc[["a"]]

In [14]: df
Out[14]:
     x
a 1  2
  2  2
b 1  1
  3  1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pd.IndexSlice`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers) to represent slices of a `pd.MultiIndex`

```
df.loc[pd.IndexSlice['a', :], :] = 2
print df

a 1  2
  2  2
b 1  1
  3  1
```

Other examples

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([['a', 1], ['a', 2], ['b', 1], ['b', 3]]), data={'x': 1})

df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, 1], :] = 9

print df

     x
a 1  9
  2  1
b 1  9
  3  1
```

Or

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([['a', 1], ['a', 2], ['b', 1], ['b', 3]]), data={'x': 1})

df.loc[pd.IndexSlice['b', 3], :] = 31415

print df

         x
a 1      1
  2      1
b 1      1
  3  31415
```